# Use browser autocomplete with jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, autocomplete

I am trying to use native autocomplete functions of browsers as Chrome or Firefox when I create dynamically severals input, using jQuery.

I created a "false" tag form with an action which does nothing, and my input inside.
The following HTML code is created by my javascript script :

```
<form action="javascript:" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
    <input value="20090801" type="text" id="iptFC80516B" name="EVE1003" autocomplete="on EVE1003">
</form>
```

This works well when I write something in the input and press "enter"; when I go to an input with the same name and begin to write the same thing, the autocomplete stuff works.
But when I write something in the input and click out of the input, it does not work

I tried two things:

1.sumbit the form when focus out of the input:

```
$("#<myInputId>").focusout(function(){
    var prtForm = $(this).closest("form");
    if(prtForm.length){         
        prtForm.submit();
    }
});
```

2.simulate an enter press when focus out :

```
$("#<myInputId>").focusout(function(){
    var prtForm = $(this).closest("form");
    if(prtForm.length){         
        var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
        e.which = 13;
        e.keyCode = 13;
        $(this).trigger(e);
    }
});
```

Using debug mode in my browsers, I can see that I am actually entering in the focusout function.

Any ideas ? thanks in advance !

Comment: The check `if(prtForm.length)` should be `if (prtForm.length !== 0)`. Moreover I suggest you to use [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) instead of focusout.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Nevertheless, I have the same behaviour with blur function, and changing the check as you suggered.

Comment: Are you binding the event before or after the element is created?

Comment: The element is created before the event being binded. Actually, if a replace the action attribute of my form by `action="javascript:alert('test');"`, it works : the alert is shown when I click out of my input, by entering in my focusout (or blur, I tested too) function.